# How to construct an operator $T$ such that $T^2=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H}$ denote a separable Hilbert space of dimension $2 \leq n \leq \infty$. How can I construct a non-zero bounded linear operator $T:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ such that $T^2 = 0$?

Comment: This is so easy that I suppose that you forgot something. Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

If $\{e_n\}$ is a Hilbert base, define
$$T(e_1)=e_2$$
$$T(e_n)=0\text{ for }n\ge 2$$

Comment: But is this operator linear?